# nginx custom header validation

Tags: nginx

I and trying to evaluate a header value for certain locations. Something like this:

```
location /risksecretspoc {
    set my_header $http_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER;
    if($my_header != 'some-value') {
        return 403;
    }
    proxy_set_header    Host riskservicesdev.mydomain.co.za;
    proxy_pass          https://rsk-generic-dev.mydomain.co.za;
}
```

The error I'm getting is: 
nginx: [emerg] invalid variable name "my_header" in /etc/nginx/nginx_default.conf:17

Comment: don't you have to add $ before your variable? your header is not a default one (like x-forwarded-for or others) its a variable. Have you tried set $my_header $http_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to enable underscores in headers

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

Then you can compare the custom header

```
location /risksecretspoc {
    if ( $http_my_custom_header != 'some-value' ) {
        return 403;
    }
    proxy_set_header    Host riskservicesdev.mydomain.co.za;
    proxy_pass          https://rsk-generic-dev.mydomain.co.za;
}
```

The spaces after the if is important!

Comment: Is it possible to perform this in kubernetes through ingress